# AWS SES email keeps going to SPAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

So in my aws Lambda, I'm sending SES email to users but the email keeps going to their **SPAM** or **PROMOTION** tab for gmail. Any suggestion?

I have added DKIM as well.

Comment: Have you checked for large bounce or complaint counts. Take a look at the SES dashboard to view the health of the domain.

Comment: It's possible someone reported it as spam. First I would follow Chris Williams's advice, and then I would review your emails and make sure they follow best practices and don't raise any red flags

Comment: Are You using the dedicated ip's? If You bought a dedicated ip, and decided to warm it up yourself such situation can occur when the warmup is not finished.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur as a result of poor reputation. This is all visible within SES from your domains health dashboard.

Lookout for increase in bounces or complaints as these could lead to a negative impact on the reputation.

Amazon have a [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sender-reputation.html) on how to use the dashboard as well as steps in mitigation. I would advise that you remove emails from any lists that have high bounce rates as well as alarming with automation to remediate negative behavioural changes.

Comment: thanks for this comment! i appreciate it. on my dashboard i have 0% complaint and Bounce rate and complaint rate both in HEALTHY status.  My bounce rate is 0.13% .